# Relógio que muda de cor

Tags: javascript, jquery

eu tenho o seguinte código em JavaScript

```
    function carregar() {
var msg = document.getElementById('msg')
var img = document.getElementById('imagem')
var data = new Date()
var hora = data.getHours()
var min = data.getMinutes()
var seg = data.getSeconds()
setTimeout('carregar()', 500)
msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hora}:${min}:${seg}.`
if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
    //BOM DIA!
    img.src = 'amanhecer-redonda.png'
    document.body.style.background = '#FAF1FA'
} else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
    //BOA TARDE!
    img.src = 'entardecer-redonda.png'
    document.body.style.background = '#EFC529'
} else {
    //BOA NOITE!
    img.src = 'anoitecer-redonda.png'
     document.body.style.background = '#4428FF'
}}
```

No entanto, eu gostaria de convertê-lo em JQuery, como forma de estudos. Estou desde ontem tentando, cheguei até aqui. Poderiam me dar uma luz?

```
$(function carregar () {
var msg = $('#msg')
var img = $('#imagem')
var data = new Date()
var hora = data.getHours()
var min = data.getMinutes()
var seg = data.getSeconds()
setTimeout('carregar ()', 500).html(`Agora são ${hora}:${min}:${seg}.`)
    if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
        //BOM DIA!
        img.src = 'amanhecer-redonda.png'
        document.body.style.background = '#FAF1FA'
    } else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
        //BOA TARDE!
        img.src = 'entardecer-redonda.png'
        document.body.style.background = '#EFC529'
    } else {
        //BOA NOITE!
        img.src = 'anoitecer-redonda.png'
        document.body.style.background = '#4428FF'
    }

    }}
```

Comment: `$(function carregar () {` não precisa disso, continue usando `function carregar () {`. Coloque os pontos onde tem dúvida, só colocar o código na pergunta é algo como "olhem ai e resolvam pra mim", percebe? Comente o que tem dúvida, o que não está conseguindo alterar para ai sim podemos ajudar

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas `getHours` [retorna um número entre 0 e 23](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours#Return_value), então não precisa testar se é maior que zero. Pode ser apenas `if (hora < 12) { manhã } else if (hora < 18) { tarde }  else { noite }` - No `else if` também não precisa testar se é maior que 12, porque se não fosse, teria entrado no primeiro `if` (se chegou neste `else` é porque com certeza é >= 12, então só precisa testar se é < 18).

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu não sabia disso. Muito obrigado pelo ensinamento, isso ajuda a deixar o código mais limpo

@RicardoPontual o $ é por causa disso

```
$(document ).ready() 
```
isso pode ser resumido com apenas um $.

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo parecido com

```js
function carregar() {
    var $msg = $('#msg');
    var $img = $('#imagem');
    var data = new Date();
    var hora = data.getHours();
    var min = data.getMinutes();
    var seg = data.getSeconds();
    setTimeout('carregar()', 500)
    $msg.html(`Agora são ${hora}:${min}:${seg}.`);
    if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
        //BOM DIA!
        $img.attr('src', 'amanhecer-redonda.png');
        $('body').css({background: '#FAF1FA'});
    } else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
        //BOA TARDE!
        $img.attr('src', 'entardecer-redonda.png');
        $('body').css({background: '#EFC529'});
    } else {
        //BOA NOITE!
        $img.attr('src', 'anoitecer-redonda.png');
        $('body').css({background: '#4428FF'});

    }
}
```

Primeiro mudamos a forma de recuperar os elementos utilizando `$()`. Assim onde tinha `document.getElementById('msg')` foi colocado `$('#msg')` que é como se recupera elementos em JQuery. O mesmo vale para o elemento **imagem**.

Após isso substitui-se `innerHTML` pelo método `.html()` e também a forma de mudar os atributos com `attr()` e o estilo do body com `css()`.

Perceba que nas variáveis em que recuperamos os elementos foi colocado o cifrão. Não tem nada de especial mas nos indica de que aquela variável é um elemento selecionado.

### Algumas melhorias

Por fim, é possível melhoras esse código fazendo fazendo uso de `setInterval()` ao invés de `setTimeout()` com recursividade.

O elemento `body` também pode ser criado no começo da função junto com os outros. A ideia é a mesma, só tenha atenção que nesse caso não haverá a cerquilha, seria algo parecido com:

```js
var $body = $('body');
```

Daí na hora de mudar a cor de fundo bastava fazer

```js
$body.css({background: '#FAF1FA'});
```

Comment: Sim! Quando eu perguntei isso, ainda estava nas minhas primeiras aulas, atualmente ainda tenho muito o que aprender, mas consigo ver melhor o código e vocês me ajudaram muito. É sempre bom ter com quem contar!!